# Gson: Not a JSON Object

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following String passed to server:

```
{
    "productId": "",
    "sellPrice": "",
    "buyPrice": "",
    "quantity": "",
    "bodies": [
        {
            "productId": "1",
            "sellPrice": "5",
            "buyPrice": "2",
            "quantity": "5"
        },
        {
            "productId": "2",
            "sellPrice": "3",
            "buyPrice": "1",
            "quantity": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

which is a valid json for http://jsonlint.com/

I want to get the bodies array field.

That's how I'm doing it:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject object = gson.toJsonTree(value).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray jsonBodies = object.get("bodies").getAsJsonArray();
```

But on the second line I'm getting exception listed below:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Not a JSON Object: "{\"productId\":\"\",\"sellPrice\":\"\",\"buyPrice\":\"\",\"quantity\":\"\",\"bodies\":[{\"productId\":\"1\",\"sellPrice\":\"5\",\"buyPrice\":\"2\",\"quantity\":\"5\"},{\"productId\":\"2\",\"sellPrice\":\"3\",\"buyPrice\":\"1\",\"quantity\":\"1\"}]}"
```

How to do it properly then ?

Comment: May want to take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15116323/2044733. The second option, beginning "To use JsonObject," looks like exactly what you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have used the `parse` method as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15116323/2044733 before and it's worked.

The actual code would look like

```
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
jsonParser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
```

From [the docs](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html#getAsJsonObject()) it looks like you're running into the error described where your it thinks your `toJsonTree` object is not the correct type.

The above code is equivalent to

```
JsonElement jelem = gson.fromJson(json, JsonElement.class);
```

as mentioned in another answer here and on the linked thread.

Answer (score 11):

[`Gson#toJsonTree` javadoc](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJsonTree%28java.lang.Object%29) states

> This method serializes the specified object into its equivalent
>   representation as a tree of `JsonElement`s.

That is, it basically does

```
String jsonRepresentation = gson.toJson(someString);
JsonElement object = gson.fromJson(jsonRepresentation, JsonElement.class);
```

A Java `String` is converted to a JSON String, ie. a `JsonPrimitive`, not a `JsonObject`. In other words, `toJsonTree` is interpreting the content of the `String` value you passed as a JSON string, not a JSON object.

You should use

```
JsonObject object = gson.fromJson(value, JsonObject.class);
```

directly, to convert your `String` to a `JsonObject`.

Answer (score -1):

What about *JsonArray jsonBodies = object.getAsJsonArray("bodies");*

Comment: What will this change considering the exception happens on `getAsJsonObject`?