# Using Gson to convert a string object to JSON string in Java

Tags: java, json, gson

Let's say we have the following string:

```
String x = "abc";
```

My question is how would I use the Gson library to convert the given string, to the following JSON string:

```
{
   x : "abc"
}
```

Comment: please check:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128442/how-to-convert-a-string-to-jsonobject-using-gson-library

Comment: You can wrap your `String x = "abc"` into a class `StringClass` and use Gson to convert it.

Answer (score 3):

Of course I could have created a new class that wraps the string object, and convert it to a JSON string, but it didn't seem necessary. Anyway, the solution I found was this:

```
JsonObject x = new JsonObject();
x.addProperty("x", "abc");

String json = x.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-parse-json-to-java.jsp

```
class Albums {
    public String x;
}
```

Lets convert this to JSON and see how it looks

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class JavaToJsonAndBack {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Albums albums = new Albums();
        albums.x= "abc";

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        System.out.println(gson.toJson(albums));
    }
}
```

This is how the resulting JSON looks like

```
{"x":"abc"}
```