# String to Array Java to Json object

Tags: java, json

I have a Java String that contains a json object and I do not know how to get this json object from it?

My string is like this:

```
String myString = "[1,\"{\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"InstanceNumber\\\":9}\"]";
```

How can i get the json object from this String?

Comment: use gson.jar or json.jar. They have constructors for JsonObject, in which you can pass string. [Here is the link](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.6.2/)

Comment: Pleaese look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128442/how-to-convert-a-string-to-jsonobject-using-gson-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend simple plain [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) library. Pass the string in `JSONArray` and then get the `JSONObject`. For example something like below :

```
String myString = "[1,\"{\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"InstanceNumber\\\":9}\"]";
JSONArray js = new JSONArray(myString);
System.out.println(js);
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(js.getString(1));
System.out.println(obj);
```

Output :

> - [1,"{\"Status\":0,\"InstanceNumber\":9}"]
> - {"Status":0,"InstanceNumber":9}

Downloadable jar:  http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

Answer (score 1):

For sure that you need to use a library lie **Jackson** or **Gson**.

I work mostly with **gson** when I don't have complicated stuff.
So here the output of what you are asking for. I suppose that you don't have the type that you want to convert to (for that I am taking Object).

Here is the code:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Json {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Gson g = new Gson();
       String myString = "[1,\"{\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"InstanceNumber\\\":9}\"]";
       Object p = g.fromJson(myString, Object.class);
       System.out.println(p.toString());
    }

}
```

And here is the output :

```
run:
[1.0, {"Status":0,"InstanceNumber":9}]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

You may wanting to manipulate the output object as you wish (I just printed it out).
**NOTE**: Don't forget to add **gson** jar to you classpath.

Comment: Nailed it, Excellent

Answer (score 0):

You can use any Json mapping framework to deserialise the String into Java object. Below example shows how to do it with `Jackson`:

```
String myString = "[1,\"{\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"InstanceNumber\\\":9}\"]";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Object> value = mapper.readValue(myString, new TypeReference<List<Object>>() {});
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(value.get(1).toString(), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
System.out.println(map);
```

[Here's](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs) the documentation.