# Java: Best Practice to create POJO out of JSON

Tags: java, json

I am working on code written few years back. It builds POJO out of JSON. JSON has a `statusType` field. Value of all other fields are dependent on `statusType` field. If `statusType` is `SUCCESS`, fields `successCode`, `totalValue`, `concession` etc are populated, on the other hand if it is `FAILURE`, fields `errorCode`, `exceptionType`, `retryCounts` are populated.

```
{
   "statusType": "SUCCESS",
   "successCode": "20.304",
   "total": 1000
}

{
   "statusType": "FAILED",
   "errorCode": "50.31",
   "retryCounts": 2
}
```

POJO is defined like following:

```
public class JsonPOJO {
    public String statusType;
    public String successCode;
    public int retryCounts;
    public int total;
    public String errorCode;
}
```

Client code is like following:

```
JsonPOJO pojo = buildPojo();
if (pojo.getStatusCode.equals(“SUCCESS”)) {
       String successCode = pojo.getSuccessCode();
} else {
       String errorCode = pojo.getErrorCode();
}
```

Above code is scattered throughout (around 10 places). Very soon, we'll be getting another status code `"IN_PROGRESS"`, which will introduce few more fields in JSON and then POJO will have few more fields and consequently more if/else statements throughout the code checking for `statusType`. I don't want to go through this route. I want to elegantly refactor code, so that if I get another status code (for example, `"SUSPENDED"`), I need not touch whole codebase again.

I couldn't find (maybe my Googling skills suck) any pattern, in general, to handle this kind of situation, so I am reaching out to experts here for their opinions/thoughts.

Comment: Unless you require building something from scratch yourself, consider using a library like GSON, which already has this problem covered well, [see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128442/how-to-convert-a-string-to-jsonobject-using-gson-library).

Comment: You can look at some thing like GSON or jackson libs which will help you in creating the same

Comment: Thanks, it'll solve JSON parsing problem. Is there any better way to refactor above code so that I won't need to add another if statement in client code at multiple places when new status code comes?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new status code alone doesn't add more fields. If you add more JSON, you need to update the Java, otherwise, you can't get the new fields.

I know Jackson has the option to store all extra JSON values into a Hashmap. I've not used Gson enough to see that feature.

However, you can also forget about writing Java yourself and use a [Maven plugin](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/blob/master/README.md) to generate your classes simply from an JSON schema definition

Comment: Thanks, it'll solve JSON parsing problem. Is there any better way to refactor above code so that I won't need to add another if statement in client code at multiple places when new status code comes?

Comment: You can use a Hashmap for the status and the Command Pattern, but you need to then refactor the code into a bunch of classes rather than simple if / switch statement. https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-command also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554180/why-is-the-if-statement-considered-evil